# How to add Microsoft Store App to Windows Defender Controlled Folder Access Whitelist

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender, controlled-folder-access, microsoft-store

Is there a way to automatically whitelist all Mircosoft Store Apps without the need to mess with the access permissions of `Program Files > WindowsApps` folder?

Of course you can add every single `.exe` file to the whitelist, but for that one has to mess around with the access permissions of the above mentioned folder. Which looks a bit like that:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am able to get access to that folder, but I'm not comfortable to do so. Should I gain access and <del>add those `.exe` files to the whitelist</del> (*EDIT:* UWP apps don't possess `.exe` files as pointed out by Ramhound.) that way?

*EDIT:* So my original question is answered, because it just doesn't make sense to whitelist the `Program Files > WindowsApps` folder with a wildcard of some sort. This raises the question: How can I still use Windows Defender Controlled Access while excluding all UWP apps?

Comment: Oh... didn't know that. Thank you! So how can this be done?

Comment: I want to continue using the Windows Defender Controlled Access (WDCA) functionality, because I also run non UWP apps. But I think I don't grasp the whole situation good enough yet: UWP apps are sandboxed, so WDCA isn't necessary there. If I disable it UWP apps can't make hostile changes anyways, but then other programs could. So I want to leave WDCA on, but giving some apps (Affinity Photo (UWP) in particular) write priviledges to my protected folders. How can this be done?

Comment: I didn't add the UWP folder to this list. I want to make sure that my UWP programs have the write permissions to my Desktop, Documents, etc. folders that I have protected from being modified by WDCA.

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I stopped using Windows.